# Filter Warnings In Error List Windows In Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I just recently got the approval to upgrade our project from .NET 1.1. to .NET 4.  I loaded up the project in Visual Studio 2010 and I've got it compiled and working.  However as is to be expected there are over 3000 warnings I need to start looking at and handling.  The problem is this solution has about 20 projects in it.  So what I'd like to be able to do is filter the warnings on project.  So I could say only show warnings for this project.  Does anyone know if this is possible in Visual Studio 2010 or if there is an add-on I can add?

Comment: Why do you have 300 warnings?

Comment: Because we just upgraded from .net 1.1 to .net 4 and obviously a lot of things changed between then and now so things that weren't warnings before are now warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is old and you're probably not looking for an answer anymore, but I found it with Google and thought I'd that perhaps other people finding this question might be helped with an answer (or suggestion at least).

I don't know if there is a really good way to do this, but a way that is probably acceptable is to unload all of the projects except one which does not depend on another project with warnings. You might have to build that project then and you should get a list of warnings for just that project. If you're done with one project, you can proceed with another one (that can depend on the first one).

Comment: This is a solid solution, with the exception that when you have projects with dependencies on other projects, you're frequently unable to unload and build.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out how to filter/search these warnings but you can sort the warnings by clicking on the Project column.

Comment: Found a way to do this.  Click on top bar titled "Error List".  Ctrl+A to select all and Ctrl+C to copy.  You can then paste it to an Excel spreadsheet to do whaterver you want with it.

Comment: The problem is: double clicking on a warning brings you to the point where the problem is _inside visual studio_, this is no more true if you copy the warning in excel